# How to test keyup with addEventListener

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I want to test `handleKeyPress` method, but when i simulate keyup, then i have this error: `Expected spy to have been called, but it was not called.`

```js
//App.js

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyPress)
    }
    
    handleKeyPress = (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === 38) {
            this.setState({
                up: true
            })
        }
    }
    
    
//App.test.js
    
    it('check handleKeyPress with keyup', ()=>{
        let instance = wrapper.instance()
        let handleKeyPress = spyOn(instance, 'handleKeyPress')
        wrapper.simulate('keyup', {keyCode: 38})
        expect(handleKeyPress).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are simulating the keyup event on your component wrapper but adding the keyup event listener to the document object. The [Common Gothcas](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html#common-gotchas) section mentions some stuff about event propagation not working as you would expect.

The only way I can think to get this working would be to spy on `document.addEventListener` and manually call the handler in your test file.

```
it('check handleKeyPress with keyup', () => {

    // save keyup event handler added to document
    let keyUpHandler;
    document.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, handler) => {
        if (event === 'keyup') {
          keyUpHandler = handler;
        }
    });

    // render component
    wrapper = shallow(...); 
    let instance = wrapper.instance()
    let handleKeyPress = jest.spyOn(instance, 'handleKeyPress')

    // call the keyup handler with the event data
    keyUpHandler({ keyCode: 38 })
    expect(handleKeyPress).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```